# RoR with other languages (Node.js, React.js, Laravel, Vue.js, Python)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scrum

I am new to RoR as a scrum master and I am not sure whether RoR alone is okay for our web dev projects. The company I work for uses RoR already but I keep receiving proposals from web dev vendor teams on using other languages (Node.js, React.js, Laravel, Vue.js, Python). Is it fine to use RoR exclusively and dismiss the other languages for this company?

Comment: This question is likely too broad as written. You've mixed up back ends (Node.js, Laravel, and Python) which directly compete with Ruby On Rails with front ends (React.js and Vue.js) which *can* work with Ruby On Rails. [Rails can be used as an API-only server](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) to be used by many front-end frameworks. Finally, you can split your monolithic app up into [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) which can then use whatever technologies they like. Each of these are broad topics on their own.

Comment: Hi @Schwern! thank you for your response. I agree it is too broad. So from your comment, I can use Ruby for my back-end and others for front-end (React.js and Vue,js)?

Comment: Yes. One of the weaknesses of many frameworks is their monolithic approach wielding the back and front end together. Rails in API mode lets you break this dependency allowing the excellent back end features of Rails to be queried by modern web frameworks. This allows your team to transition to a more up-to-date web framework while retaining a familiar back end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a [Scrum Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(software_development)#Scrum_master) you should not be making this decision at all. Your job is to "remove impediments to the ability of the team to deliver the product goals and deliverables". And, I do not mean to offend, but your question shows a lack of understanding of the subject. You're new to Rails. And you've mixed up programming languages (Python) with frameworks (Node.js, React.js, Laravel, Vue.js) and back end considerations (Python, Laravel, Node.js) with front end ones (React.js and Vue.js).

Technological decisions such as which frameworks and languages to use are not to be made by the Scrum Master. If you have any role in these decisions, it would be to educate yourself on the topics (possibly by discussing them with your technical team members), and to facilitate discussion and making of a choice by the [stakeholders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_stakeholder).

Comment: Did you mean to start with: As a "scrum master" ....